# How to switch to my radeon 530 graphics card on xubuntu 18.10?

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I would like to use my radeon 530 graphics card while I'm playing games but I don't know how to do it. When I run glxinfo while playing a game, it shows intel gpu as active and I would like to change that. I checked other threads but they are about installing drivers and I do not have any knowledge about if I should install extra driver or not. My distro is xubuntu 18.10 and my lspci output is like this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev c3)
```